# NAND Block size confusion

Tags: u-boot, flash-memory

I have a fundamental doubt regarding NAND chip,
We are trying to bring up custom board based on DM365,

We are trying to boot from the NAND,

NAND used is from micron MT29F8G08ABABA. (1Giga bytes = 8 Gigabits)

Organization
– Page size x8: 4320 bytes (4096 + 224 bytes)
– Block size: 128 pages (512K +28 K bytes)
– Plane size: 2 planes x 1024 blocks per plane
– Device size: 8Gb: 2048 blocks

Now as per datasheet of MT29F8G08BABA i think block size is (512K+224)bytes.

But in u-boot terminologies they use Sector size for NAND device.
Because when i use command
   `nand info`
from u-boot commandline,
I get nand size as follows

```
Device 0: NAND 1GiB 3,3V 8-bit, sector size 256 KiB
```

**Is this sector size is block size(which is actually 512k as per datasheet) or Environment sector?**
NAND read/Write is working fine from u-boot, There is no issue as such.
So i just want to understand these terminologies.

Now if this is environment sector size then is there any way to get block size information from U-boot ?

Can somebody please enlighten me on this ?

Thank you,

Regards,
Ankur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems eraseblock size is nothing but the sector size.
Check below link for more information.

[Updated link to TI E2E forum question](https://e2e.ti.com/support/processors-group/processors/f/processors-forum/311521/confusion-regarding-block-size-in-nand-chip-and-nand-sector-size-in-u-boot/1084615?tisearch=e2e-sitesearch&keymatch=%2525252525252520user%252525252525253A165695#1084615)

Regards,
Ankur

Comment: Dear Ankur, the link you've posted is no longer hosted (Page Not Found)

Comment: @ZbigniewMazur Try new link